# copying a form textfield value into a report textfield

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an access form in wich a user can enter project details (like project number, name and ordering party etc etc)

[image]

I also have a few reports with a header. I would like the values that are entered in the project detail form to be automatically inserted into the header text (orange selected) fields.

[image]

How can I do this?

I have added the tags vba and sql, because I am willing to use these ways if it is otherwise impossible to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way to do this would be to set the `Control Source` of the text boxes on the Report to point to the corresponding text boxes on the Form. So, the Report text boxes would have a `Control Source` that looks something like:

```
=[Forms]![Form1]![txtProjectName]
```

Comment: Where can i find the Control Source?

Comment: Open the report in Design View, then right-click on a text box and choose "Properties". The `Control Source` is the first item on the "Data" tab of the Property Sheet.